# How can we select rows based on the column condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table like the following:

| id | transaction_id | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2100 | 20010904 | item1 |
| 2100 | 20010904 | item2 |
| 2100 | 20010904 | item3 |
| 2101 | 20010904 | item1 |
| 2101 | 20010904 | item4 |
| 2102 | 20010904 | item1 |
| 2102 | 20010904 | item2 |
| 2102 | 20010904 | item3 |
| 2102 | 20010905 | item4 |

`id` is the people's id, `transaction_id` is the id for that transaction for that person; `item` are the items included in that transaction.

I want to select rows which `item` not contain item1 and item4 together in the same `transaction_id`.

So the expected results will be:

| id | transaction_id | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2100 | 20010904 | item1 |
| 2100 | 20010904 | item2 |
| 2100 | 20010904 | item3 |
| 2102 | 20010904 | item1 |
| 2102 | 20010904 | item2 |
| 2102 | 20010904 | item3 |
| 2102 | 20010905 | item4 |

I know how to select rows that `item` only contains 'item1', but I am not sure about how to select rows that `item` not contain 'item1' and 'item4' in the same transaction_id. In fact, the cases are more complicate. In some cases, I want to select rows that `item` does not contain 'item1','item4','item5','item6' in the same transaction_id.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: `I want to select rows which item not contain item1 and item4 together in the same transaction_id` Your expected result does not seems to match the description. Why is `20010904` in the result when both `item1` and `item4` existed in the same transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Having COUNT()` with `GROUP BY` can help in your case:

```
SELECT id, transaction_id, item 
FROM TransactionTable
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM TransactionTable
    WHERE item IN ('item1', 'item4')  
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item) != 2
) Q
```

Comment: It should be ```NOT IN ('item1','item4')```, because I am trying to have the rows that not include 'item1' and 'item4' in the same order.

Comment: @KT.Thompson I'm handling that in the `HAVING` clause as ` count != 2`, so it will return your expected result

Comment: What if I want to select the rows that NOT contains 'item1', 'item4', 'item5' and 'item6' in the same transaction_id?

Comment: Might be this will help you. 
select tt.id,tt.transaction_id,tt.item,tt2.transactions from testtable tt left join (SELECT id,group_concat(CONCAT('"', replace(item, ',', '","'), '"')) as transactions FROM `testtable` group by id) tt2 ON tt2.id = tt.id

Comment: @KT.Thompson Change the WHERE clause to `WHERE item IN ('item1', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6')` and the HAVING clause to `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item) != 4`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a left anti-join approach:

```sql
SELECT id, transaction_id, item
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE item IN ('item1', 'item4')
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING MIN(item) <> MAX(item)
) t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE
    t2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE a 
WHERE CONCAT(a.transction_id ,if(substr(a.item,-1)>3,'item',a.item ) NOT IN (

  (SELECT 
    CONCAT('item',transction_id) FROM TABLE a  
     GROUP BY transaction_id HAVING  COUNT(*)>3 /* total filted count*/
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select id, item, count(case when item in ('item1','item4') then 1 else 0 end ) over (partition by transaction_id, id) as cate
from yourtable) where cate <>2;
```